# I know this DE is solvable...

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with a seemingly simple looking diff equ

$$
x\frac {d^{2}y} {dx^{2}}+2y=0
$$

---

$$
\rightarrow \frac {d^{2}y} {dx^{2}}+2\frac {y} {x}=0
$$

$v= (\frac {y} {x})$ substitution isn't working as it eventually shows:
$$
xv''+v'+2v=0
$$

which isn't any easier.  That variable is making my blood pressure go up.

I know I'm looking past something stupid.

Comment: This is a form of the Bessel differential equation, see, e.g., here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: If you type the equation into WolframAlpha, you'll see that the solution is expressed using Bessel functions.  This makes it *likely* that the solution cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Ohhhh... Yes, thank both of you!  I knew it was a little harder than it looked.  If I have time I might upload my own solution later.

Answer (score 4):

Don't feel bad about not being able to solve this.  Many (maybe, most) easily expressed differential equations cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions.  In spite of this, [standard existence and uniqueness theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions) often guarantee the existence of solutions.  When the solution of an important class of differential equations cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, we give the solution a name, in this case, the Bessel functions.  Functions generated in this fashion are generally called [special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions).

Many mathematical software packages know about special functions.  For example, if you type this differential equation into WolframAlpha, you'll get all kinds of information about the solution.

Text entered: [x*y'' + 2y = 0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*y%27%27%20%2b%202y%20=%200)

Output:

[image]

Note that the solution is expressed in terms of functions denoted $J_1$ and $Y_1$, called [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).  Also, in spite of the fact that there's no simple formula, several plots are generated.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  It's been a loooong time since I've seen Bessel functions.  I'll plan on writing up a formal solution later.

Answer (score -1):

I thought the wolfram alpha page on Bessel function lacked definition, therefore I will provide the full derivation of it, so lurkers like me can get review from time to time, and since some applications require the full notation.

---

Starting with a function similar to:
$$
y''+f(x)y'+g(x)y=0
$$
You're looking for two functions$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that satisfies the differential equation and $y$ is the expression.

Starting with $y$:
$$
y=x^{a}J_{\pm}(bx^{c}) = x^{a}J(z);  z=bx^{c}
$$

Taking derivatives of $x$, in which $J$ is a function of $z$, therefore implementing the chain rule:
$$
\frac {dy} {dx}=ax^{a-1}J+x^{a}(\frac {dJ} {dz})(\frac {dz} {dx})
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac {dy} {dx}=ax^{a-1}J+x^{a}(\frac {dJ} {dz})bcx^{c-1}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac {dy} {dx}=ax^{a-1}J+bcx^{a+c-1}(\frac {dJ} {dz})
$$
Now taking the second derivative
$$
\Rightarrow \frac {d^{2}y} {dx^{2}}=a(a-1)x^{a-2}J+bcx^{a+c-2}(2a+c-1)\frac {dJ} {dz} + b^{2}c^{2}x^{a+2c-2}\frac {d^{2}J} {dz^{2}}
$$
Now replace $\frac {d^{2}} {dz^{2}}$ in the last equation into the differential equation
$$
J''=-(\frac {1} {z}J'+(1-\frac {m^{2}} {z^{2}})J)
$$

Now determine$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that
$$
y''+f(x)y'+g(x)y=0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow [a(a-1)x^{a-2}J+bcx^{a+c-2}(2a+c-1)\frac {dJ} {dz} + b^{2}c^{2}x^{a+2c-2}\frac {d^{2}J} {dz^{2}}]+f(x)[ax^{a-1}J+bcx^{a+c-1}(\frac {dJ} {dz})]+g(x)[x^{a}J(z)]=0
$$

$$
\Rightarrow [a(a-1)x^{a-2}J+bcx^{a+c-2}(2a+c-1)\frac {dJ} {dz} + b^{2}c^{2}x^{a+2c-2}[-\frac{1}{bx^{c}}(\frac {dJ} {dz})-(1-\frac {m^{2}}{bx^{c}})J]+f(x)[ax^{a-1}J+bcx^{a+c-1}(\frac {dJ} {dz})]+g(x)[x^{a}J(z)]=0
$$

And group all of the terms into two term, ie:
$$
()\frac {dJ} {dz}+()J=0
$$

With each set $()=0$

This gives:
$$
f(x)=\frac {(1-2a)} {x}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=-(\frac {c^{2}m^{2}-a^{2}} {x^{2}})+b^{2}c^{2}x^{2c-2}
$$

---

And thus, once simplified, substitution reveals the famous Bessel Function:
$$
\therefore \frac {d^{2}y} {dx^{2}}+\frac {1-2a} {x}\frac {dy} {dx}-[(\frac {c^{2}m^{2}-a^{2}} {x^{2}})+b^{2}c^{2}x^{2c-2}]y=0
$$
with solutions:
$$
y=k_1x^{a}J_m(bx^{c}+k_2x^{a}(bx^{c})
$$

---

Therefore, given the DE:
$$
xy''-2y=0
$$

comparing the Bessel Function, we can see that
$$
1-2a=0; 
$$
$$
b^{2}c^{2}=2;
$$
$$
c^{2}m^{2}-a^{2}=0;
$$ 
$$
2c-2=-1
$$

---

Set up a system of equations using these, solve for the constants, and plug into the Bessel solution: $y=k_1x^{a}J_m(bx^{c}+k_2x^{a}(bx^{c})$, for the answer

Comment: Did I miss anything?

Comment: Writing all of that Latex makes me want to do my taxes or something.